# 4G LTE Device [USB Tethering]--> Raspberry Pi [Ethernet]--> Router, is this possible?

Tags: linux, router, usb, raspberry-pi, hotspot

Ok, some background info first:

1. I run a Debian fork (Netrunner Blackbird, right now) for my daily and this has allowed me to get fairly comfortable with Terminals (Konsole on KDE, mostly)...
2. I will be getting an unlimited 4G LTE SIM card for like $80/mo. (mobile hotspot and whatnot).
3. I will put said SIM card in either a Tablet (with no Wireless AC) or in an "AirCard" with no WiFi capabilities at all (looks like a USB flash drive).
4. I have a Raspberry Pi 3B and Raspberry Pi 3B+ (I also have a Pi Zero & Pi Zero W).
5. Generally, I'm fairly new to advanced networking. (e.g. I know that I need to set a static local IP on my router for the Kore Remote on my phone to consistently connect to my Pi, but I have no idea what DLNA, DNS, DHCP, IPv4, IPv6, etc. are, nor what they do).

So...

I want to go:

4G LTE Tablet/AirCard [USB Tethering]--> Raspberry Pi [Ethernet]--> D-Link Router

Is this possible?

**I should state my end goal:** To use my hotspot as the source for the router's WAN connection.

I know that Tethering a Tablet to a Pi is pretty straight forward (turn on Dev Opt, turn on USB Debug, plug in phone to Pi with USB, turn on USB Tethering), but I wasn't sure if the AirCard was defaulted to "USB Tethering" mode or some other protocol that most computers will detect, but is not used.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I somehow pass the internet connection from my 4G LTE chosen device through the Pi to my Router, so I can connect phones, computers, tablets, etc., to my Router for internet?
2. Can an AirCard just connect directly to a router, if the router has a USB port? (I think the one on my router is used for DLNA stuff...)
3. Is there an easier way to do this where I don't have to spend anymore money? (I also have an old laptop with no screen that I can use, maybe... and an ARM-processor chromebook.)

I figure I'd be setting all this up using my linux computer and so, I'd probably need the linux terminal commands to do to set it all up.

Comment: Raspberry Pi can be used as a WiFi access point i.e. WiFi router.

Comment: @Biswapriyo But a Raspberry Pi doesn't have 802.11ac and my router does. I need that for this home solution.

Comment: “…I'd probably need the linux terminal commands to do to set it all up.” Voting to close because you are asking the community to do all of the work here without any real effort on your part. The reality? Yes, this can be done. The specifics? Sorry but this site does not provide bespoke tutorials like this.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a Raspberry Pi to achieve your goal. With Android 11 onwards you can use ethernet tethering. You can buy a USB-C to Ethernet adapter. Plug the USB-C end into your Android 11 device, plug the ethernet end into your router. Turn on Ethernet tethering in Android. Make sure WiFi on your phone is off so that you are using your mobile cellular connection for internet. I have such a USB-C to ethernet adapter and can inform that this works very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - this is possible, to answer your overall question, generally:

> 4G LTE Device [USB Tethering]--> Raspberry Pi [Ethernet]--> Router, is
> this possible?

Yes, if I've understood:

- you want to share your mobile/cellular phone or device's internet connection with wired ethernet devices
- you want to use a Raspberry PI to make the above possible, by plugging in your phone to a USB port of the Raspberry PI and plugging in a router into the ethernet port of the Raspberry Pi

The answer is - yes, according to these links, in order of relevance to you:

- **Update 2023** Additional bullet point: You don't need a Raspberry Pi to achieve your goal, from what I understand. With Android 11 onwards you can use ethernet tethering. You can buy a USB-C to Ethernet adapter. Plug the USB-C end into your Android 11 device, plug the ethernet end into your router. Turn on Ethernet tethering in Android. Make sure WiFi on your phone is off so that you are using your mobile cellular connection for internet. I have such a USB-C to ethernet adapter and can inform that this works very well. It now depends if your original device when asking this question now supports Android 11, which I may doubt unfortunately. In that case then the original Raspberry Pi idea would still apply or using a device that does support Android 11.
- [How to turn the Raspberry Pi into a Gateway to mobile phone
  internet](https://blog.michael.franzl.name/2017/02/28/raspberry-pi-gateway-mobile-internet/)
- [Share USB tethered phone to Raspberry Pi 4 LAN port](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106871/share-usb-tethered-phone-to-raspberry-pi-4-lan-port)
- [How can I share my raspberry pi 3's internet to a router's WAN
  port?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59713/how-can-i-share-my-raspberry-pi-3s-internet-to-a-routers-wan-port)
- [Raspberry Pi 3 B+ to Samsung Galaxy S7 USB Tethering Inactive eth1
  Interface](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96592/raspberry-pi-3-b-to-samsung-galaxy-s7-usb-tethering-inactive-eth1-interface)

I am looking to do the same thing at some point in the future - with 4G and also 5G.

I have a Samsung A90 5G phone as a second phone with a SIM that will provide 5G once the signal is available in my area, in the meantime before that, it'll be 4G/4G+. I will be plugging it into the above setup to share this connection with the wired devices in my home.

The benefit of this setup is portable - in several ways:

- you can take the phone with you when you go out. This assumes that you don't need to connect to home whilst out, e.g. for IoT things: lights, heating, projects, personal server etc, or that you live with others who need the internet when you are out.
- If you do need to connect to home, or need to have a home connection running when you're out/away, then an option could be to use another spare phone, with a more basic spec but still 4G or 4G and with a Pay-as-you-go (PAYG) SIM card. All this to keep costs down. If you run out of data allowance on this setup, you can top-up remotely, of course, via the provider's app on another phone (GiffGaff in UK is very good for this, as it enables accounts on other phones to be managed, all the other networks' apps seem to need to be running on the phone for the network, which can be inconvenient). Once topped up, your home connection, based on PAYG is restored.
- If you take the (better) phone with you and you have a more basic phone plugged into your RaspberryPi for internet at home, then with the better phone you can tether it as my point one says, but also if you use Speedify app on your device e.g. laptop that you're tethering to, then your laptop can bond the mobile phone internet connection with other internet connections, e.g. train, Cafe or Hotel Wifi, and/or other phones. This enables a faster aggregate connection, helps 'smooth over drop-outs' e.g. with reception - e.g. with WiFi on a train, as well provide a secure VPN.
- A further option, in the UK at least is [Honest Mobile](https://honestmobile.co.uk/) which provides an add-on to switch between different providers if the signal on one is lost.
- further point on portability advantage - you could even take the whole setup somewhere else - the raspberry Pi is small enough to be portable.

Hope this is useful. I don't work for GiffGaff nor Speedify, nor Honest Mobile or any other providers mentioned above, nor have a financial interest in them. But I do use their (GiffGaff's and Speedify's) services and find them to work well.